# Regex expression to get first word after specified word

Tags: c#, regex

I'm new in the world of Regex and want to find the first sequence after a word like in the example:

```
ALEEA NARCISELOR BL. A3 NR. 1 SC. B AP. 68
```

I want to find the first word that comes after `NR`, in this case is `1`, but could be `A1` or `A`, but in this case is `1`.

What would be the regex expression for that.

Thaks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Pattern you can use:

```
(?<=NR\.)\s?\w+
```

Demo: [example](http://regexr.com?31uqc)

Comment: Use case insensitive flag: i or `(NR|nr|nR|Nr)` instead of `NR`

Answer (score 1):

This should do

```
(?<=(\s|^)NR\.\s*).*?(?=\s|$)
```

Comment: and if I want the first word?

Comment: @XandrUu would it always be `NR.`

Comment: @XandrUu the ans that you selected wud also match `NR1IS`